# Ubuntu nagios postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, nagios

I'm a french student and I have a little problem.

So I'm using Nagios with check_postgres plugin (here : https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/PostgresQL/check_postgres/details)

So I'm using this plugin with command like this :

```
check_postgres.pl -u postgres -db bddprojet --action database_size -w $1000000 -c 10000000
```

It only works if I'm logged as postgres in ubuntu (su postgres), so no problem.

But when I want to add the plugin to Nagios, I have an error message:

> ERROR: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

I have exactly the same error message if I'm logged as 'root' on ubuntu when I use the command above.

I already check my pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

host    all         all         10.0.2.15/32         trust
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

local   all             postgres                                trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I really need help, thanks in advance. Sorry for my poor english

Comment: This is not a programming question.   Ask it on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

the line `local all postgres trust` makes sure that access to all databases by the postgresql user postgres are allowed without password. By default this is "peer" instead of "trust" which then only allows access with the postgresql ubuntu user. Did you restart the postgresql server after making this change ?

The postgresql server needs to be restarted after a pg_hba.conf change.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to move the line

```
local all postgres trust
```

up *above* the other `local` line and reload the server.

Lines in `pg_hba.conf` are processed top to bottom, and the first matching line is used.

The error message shows that you forgot to reload the server after editing the file.

Comment: Thanks I moved this line at on top and it works omg ! Thanks :)